# Force building multiple projects in cruisecontrol.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am running multiple projects inside my cruisecontrol.net. These projects depend on each other. Basically if project A gets build successfully I want it to force projects B,C to get build. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the forcebuildpublisher block in your project configuration.
Take a loot at the documentation:
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/ForceBuildPublisher

Comment: This is what I use but I get the following message:
Project A already in queue, canceling new request...
I'm not sure why??

Comment: It sounds like you are not configuring your force build trigger correctly. i.e. 
<forcebuild>
   <project><!-- This is the name of your project you want to trigger --></project>
</forcebuild>

Answer (score 1):

There is a projectTrigger which you can add to your triggers block of the dependent projects. You can find the documentation for project trigger [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger)